# Security alert when deploying Nativescript app to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, nativescript

A few days after deploying my Nativescript app to Beta testers on the Google Play store I recieved an alert from Google stating:

> Security Alert: Your app contains embedded private keys or keystore files

It points to the following file which seems to be apart of the defualt node modules installed by Nativescript

> assets/app/tns_modules/node-gyp/test/fixtures/server.key

I could simply remove this file before my next deployment, but I'm hesitant to do so since it's not something I myself added. Has anyone run into this or know if it is safe to remove before I take the chance and do it anyway?

Comment: I would suggest to check your `npm` dependencies. `node-gyp` should not be included in the `*.apk` package. While NativeScript uses `npm` packager it doesn't support packages that contains binary/executable files. `node-gyp` is usually used to compile a package with C/C++ code. This scenario doesn't make much sense for NativeScript as the code will be deployed on Android/iOS which is different from your desktop/laptop.

Comment: If I look at the package.json of my main app. This dependency does not show up there. Is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to use `npm ls` to list all packages.

Comment: This is probably solved already, but I presume that this is a dependency you manually added to your npm deps. So it might be something which should've been a dev-dep rather than a production dep. Would you care to post the relevant contents of your package.json? This might be an indirect dependency...